# c# узнать разрешения на папку

Tags: c#, permissions

нашел только вариант как узнать имею ли я разрешения на папку через FileIOPermission. А нужно получить список доменных пользователей и групп которые имеют разрешения на папку и какие (чтение/запись).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e1fc3b8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev если добавите небольшой пример использования, получится хороший ответ. Пример в документации, на мой взгляд, не слишком удачный, хотя разобраться можно при желании.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev этот пример действует только если мы знаем пользователя - тогда мы можем узнать какие есть права конкретно у этого пользователя. А мне надо узнать какие стоят права на эту папки, но имен пользователей я не знаю.

Comment: @polsok вы не правы, метод приведенный в ссылке на документацию позволяет получить полный список ACL для указанного объекта ФС. Просто пример так построен, что кажется обратное. Ладно, если Леонид так и не соберется описать пример, напишу завтра для вашего случая.

Comment: @rdorn пишите. У меня нет времени на разжевывание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В официальной документации MS можно найти все необходимое, но на это требуется некоторое количество терпения и времени на эксперименты, особенно если вы раньше не сталкивались в плотную с администрированием прав доступа ФС под Windows. Описания необходимых классов и методов довольно расплывчаты и плохо покрыты демонстрационными примерами, поэтому короткая шпаргалка будет не лишней, ну а за специфическими деталями уже в документацию. Некоторые необходимые ссылки будут в конце.

Ниже консольная демка, которая покажет права всех пользователей.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //получаем дескриптор безопасности объекта ФС
        var filesecurity = File.GetAccessControl("С:\\");
        //получаем список правил безопасности связанных с объектом ФС
        var rules = filesecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
        //группируем правила по аккаунту, для одного аккаунта может быть несколько правил
        var accounts = rules.Cast<FileSystemAccessRule>().GroupBy(r => r.IdentityReference);
        foreach(var acc in accounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(acc.Key.Value);
            foreach(var rule in acc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  {rule.AccessControlType}: {rule.FileSystemRights}");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Дальнейшая модификация под ваши требования не должна составить большого труда.

Несколько важных моментов:

1. Группы правил "allow" и "deny" хранятся отдельными записями.
2. Группы правил унаследованные от родительского объекта ФС и заданные явно для текущего хранятся отдельными записями.
3. Группа правил представлена набором флагов в виде перечисления.
4. Чтение правил безопасности может быть запрещено этими же правилами, поэтому возможны исключения при отсутствии данных прав.

Полезные ссылки:

[File.GetAccessControl Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e1fc3b8(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Класс FileSecurity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Метод CommonObjectSecurity.GetAccessRules (Boolean, Boolean, Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.accesscontrol.commonobjectsecurity.getaccessrules(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Класс NTAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.principal.ntaccount(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Большая благодарочка. Проверочный путь оценила)