# Как определить права процесса если оно было запущено сторонним приложением?

Tags: c#, windows, процесс

Написал вот такой код для того чтоб можно было узнать с какими правами запущено приложение:

```cs
private static void GetRights(string argument1, string _)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
    bool finded = false;
    foreach (Process process in processes)
    {
        if (process.ProcessName == argument1 || process.Id.ToString() == argument1)
        {
            try
            {
                WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(process.StartInfo.UserName);
                WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
                string userRights = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.AccountOperator) ? "AccountOperator" :
                                    principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) ? "Administrator" :
                                    principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.BackupOperator) ? "BackupOperator" :
                                    principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Guest) ? "Guest" :
                                    principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.PowerUser) ? "PowerUser" :
                                    principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.PrintOperator) ? "PrintOperator" :
                                    principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Replicator) ? "Replicator" :
                                    principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.SystemOperator) ? "SystemOperator" :
                                    principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.User) ? "User" :
                                    "Unknown";
                Console.WriteLine($"{process.Id}:::{process.ProcessName} > {userRights}");
                finded = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to access path for process: {process.Id}:::{process.ProcessName} >> {ex.Message}");
                finded = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!finded)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("process not found");
    }
}
```

В теории этой функции должен был передаваться (id или имя процесса, None) а он должен был выводить права процесса, однако как оказалось позже WindowsBuiltInRole может выдать права процесса только если мое приложение и запустило этот процесс, в последствии чего получаю такую ошибку:

```
>$>: getrights System
Failed to access path for process: 4:::System >> Process was not started by this object, so requested information cannot be determined.
>$>:
```

а других способов узнать права приложения я не нашёл, как это можно было бы реализовать? Была дурная идея с заморозкой процессов, если выйдет то он обычный, если не выйдет то админ, однако сомнительная идея ибо может навредить другим процессам + если у моего приложения права администратора то ничего не выйдет

Comment: А System.Management пробовали может там есть что-то подходящее?

Comment: Я пробовал получить информацию о владельце процесса с помощью process["owner"] однако ничего не получилось (честно говоря уже не помню что конкретно там была за ошибка и сам код я удалил так что извините)

Comment: Я думаю в этом нет смысла. Потому что права пользователю ставятся на конкретные ресурсы. Допустим у пользователя user1 может быть доспуп к папке A1, а у пользователя user2 может не быть доступа к папке A1. Я думаю есть смысл обрабатывать и проверять при запуске доступность тех ресурсов, которые нужны для использования программы, и если они не доступны - то как то это выводить/обрабатывать.

Comment: Гуглом нашел вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765740/c-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83 это доступ на папки.

Comment: Это конечно хорошо но мне нужно узнать не доступ на парки а вообще права процесса, то есть админ он или нет

Comment: @nick_n_a 1 наверное вы меня не поняли,  процесс можно запустить от имени юзера и от имени администратора, так вот мне надо узнать есть ли у процесса права администратора (то есть запущен ли он администратором)

Comment: Ответ тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010719/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B9 WindowsIdentity - WindowsPrincipal - IsInRole. Права наследуются, если они есть - вернёт true, несли нет false. Заодно UAC там.

Comment: Спасибо, это довольно простое но еффективное решение